# Upgrading From EF 5 to 6, New Migration Swaps Columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

When upgrading a code first project from Entity Framework 5 to 6.1.1, a Model with 2 foreign keys to the same table results in the Entity Framework detecting a schema change when no change should be happening.

Here's the Model in question.

```
public class UserActivity : Activity
{
    public string UserMessage { get; set; }

    public int? OriginatorId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Originator { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public class Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserActivity>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            HasOptional(x => x.Originator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.OriginatorId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Migration that's generated when running the command Add-Migration from the Package Manager Console.

```
public partial class EF6 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "UserId", newName: "__mig_tmp__0");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "OriginatorId", newName: "UserId");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "__mig_tmp__0", newName: "OriginatorId");
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserActivities", "OriginatorId", c => c.Int());
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "OriginatorId", "dbo.Users", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", "dbo.Users", "ID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "OriginatorId", "dbo.Users");
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", c => c.Int());
        AlterColumn("dbo.UserActivities", "OriginatorId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "OriginatorId", newName: "__mig_tmp__0");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "UserId", newName: "OriginatorId");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserActivities", name: "__mig_tmp__0", newName: "UserId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.UserActivities", "UserId", "dbo.Users", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

Is there a bug in EF 6.1.1 that would explain this behavior? It looks like the EF 6 doesn't detect the 2 foreign keys properly.

As a work around, doing 2 separate migrations, the first dropping the foreign keys and a second migration to add the foreign keys seems to resolve the issue.